# How to fix the 'find' method on both the MostHomophones class and MyHashedMap interface on

Tags: java

A homophone is one of two or more words that are pronounced alike but are different in meaning or spelling; for example, the words "two", "too", and "to".

Write a Java program that uses the unordered array list implementation of the MyHashMap interface to find the most words that has the same homophones.

The file "cmudict.0.7a.txt" in common/DICTIONARIES contains a pronunciation dictionary downloaded from http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict

The page also contains a detailed description of the pronunciation dictionary. The file consists of lines of the form

```
ABUNDANT AH0 B AH1 N D AH0 N T
```

The first string is the word, which is followed by one or more phonemes (or phones) that describe the pronunciation of the word. There are 39 phonemes occurring in North American English that are used in the dictionary. The collection of 39 symbols is known as the Arpabet, for the Advanced Research Projects Agency (ARPA), which developed it in the 1970's in connection with research on speech understanding.

Call your program MostHomophones. The output is a first line containing a single integer n, which is the largest number of homophones. The n homophones follow on the next n lines, one word per line.

Exercise.

Considering only the MyHashMap operations insert, remove, and find, give the worst-case total running time and a sequence of n operations that have that running time if MyHashMap is implemented as:

(1) an unordered array list;

(2) an unordered linked list;

(3) an ordered array list.

State any assumptions you make on the implementations.

Submission:

You code for the project (60 points)

Your analysis of the BigO in the Exercise part. (21 points)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; // needed for LinkedList, Set and Map

public class MostHomophones <K, V> implements MyHashedMap<K, V>
{
    private static int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 4;
    private static int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;  
    private int capacity;   
    private static float DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;   
    private float loadFactorThreshold;  
    private int size = 0;

    public LinkedList<Map.Entry<K,V>>[] table;

    public MostHomophones()
    {
        this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY, DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);
    }

    public MostHomophones(int initialCapacity)
    {
        this(initialCapacity, DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);
    }

    public MostHomophones(int initialCapacity, float loadFactorThreshold)
    {
        if(initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        {
            this.capacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
        }
        else
        {
            this.capacity = trimToPowerOf2(initialCapacity);
        }
        this.loadFactorThreshold = loadFactorThreshold;
        table = new LinkedList[capacity];
    }

    private int trimToPowerOf2(int initialCapacity)
    {
        int capacity = 1;
        while(capacity < initialCapacity)
        {
            capacity <<= 1;
        }
        return capacity;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        size = 0;
        removeEntries();
    }

    private void removeEntries()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                table[i].clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key)
    {
        if(get(key) != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean containsValue(V value)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                LinkedList<Map.Entry<K,V>> bucket = table[i];
                for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry: bucket)
                {
                    if(entry.getValue().equals(value))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public V get(K key)
    {
        int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
        if(table[bucketIndex] != null)
        {
            LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            {
                if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                {
                    return entry.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private int hash(int hashCode)
    {
        return supplementalHash(hashCode) & (capacity - 1);
    }

    private static int supplementalHash(int h)
    {
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public Set<K> keySet()
    {
        java.util.Set<K> set = new java.util.HashSet<K>();
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[i];
                for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
                {
                    set.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
        return set;
    }

    public V put(K key, V value)
    {
        if(get(key) != null)
        {
            int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
            LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            {
                if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                {
                    V oldValue = entry.getValue();
                    entry.setValue(value);
                    return oldValue;
                }
            }
        }

        if(size >= capacity * loadFactorThreshold)
        {
            if(capacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exceeding maximum capacity");
            }
            rehash();
        }
        int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
        if(table[bucketIndex] == null)
        {
            table[bucketIndex] = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>();
        }
        table[bucketIndex].add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, V>(key, value));
        size++;
        return value;
    }

    private void rehash()
    {
        java.util.Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> set = entrySet();
        capacity <<= 1;
        table = new LinkedList[capacity];
        size = 0;
        for(Map.Entry <K, V> entry: set)
        {
            put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void remove(K key)
    {
        int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
        if(table[bucketIndex] != null)
        {
            LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            {
                if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                {
                    bucket.remove(entry);
                    size--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public Set<V> values()
    {
        java.util.Set<V> set = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[i];
                for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
                {
                    set.add(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        return set;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null && table[i].size() > 0)
            {
                for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry: table[i])
                {
                    builder.append(entry);
                }
            }
        }
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public void insert(K k, V v)
    {
        //inserthelp(root, k, e);
       // nodecount++;
    }


    public E find(K k)
    {
        //I am stuck on this one as well
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("src/project2-input.txt");

        try 
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                //Pronunciation p = new Pronunciation(line);
                //tree.insert(p.getPhonemes().length(), p);
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //ArrayList<Pronunciation> wordList = (ArrayList<Pronunciation>) tree.values();
        int max = 0;
        ArrayList homophonesList = new ArrayList();

        /**for(int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
            int len = wordList.get(i).getPhonemes().length();
            //stores all word with same lenght in this list
            ArrayList<Pronunciation> temp = (ArrayList<Pronunciation>) tree.findAll(len);
            ArrayList list =  new ArrayList();
            String find = wordList.get(i).getPhonemes();
            for(int p = 0; p < temp.size(); p++) {
                //if same put it in list
                    if(temp.get(p).getPhonemes().equals(find)) {
                        list.add(temp.get(p).getWord());
                        p++;
                    }
            }
            int ctr = list.size();
            if(ctr > max) {
                homophonesList = list;
                max = ctr;
            }
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < homophonesList.size(); k++) {
            System.out.println(homophonesList.get(k));
        }**/
    }
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;

public interface MyHashedMap <K, V> 
{
    //private static int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 4;
    //private static int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;    
    //private int capacity; 
    //private static float DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f; 
    //private float loadFactorThreshold;    
    //private int size = 0;

    //public java.util.LinkedList<Map.Entry<K,V>>[] table;

    //public MyHashedMap()
    //{
        //this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY, DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);
    //}

    //public MyHashedMap(int initialCapacity)
    //{
        //this(initialCapacity, DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);
    //}

    //public MyHashedMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactorThreshold)
    //{
        //if(initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        //{
            //this.capacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
        //}
        //else
        //{
            //this.capacity = trimToPowerOf2(initialCapacity);
        //}

        //this.loadFactorThreshold = loadFactorThreshold;
        //table = new LinkedList[capacity];
    //}

    //private int trimToPowerOf2(int initialCapacity);
    //{
        //int capacity = 1;
        //while(capacity < initialCapacity)
        //{
            //capacity <<= 1;
        //}
        //return capacity;
    //}

    public void clear();
    //{
        //size = 0;
        //removeEntries();
    //}

    //private void removeEntries();
    //{
        //for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        //{
            //if(table[i] != null)
            //{
                //table[i].clear();
            //}
        //}
    //}

    public boolean containsKey(K key);
    //{
        //if(get(key) != null)
        //{
            //return true;
        //}
        //else
        //{
            //return false;
        //}
    //}

    public boolean containsValue(V value);
    //{
        //for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        //{
            //if(table[i] != null)
            //{
                //LinkedList<Entry<K,V>> bucket = table[i];
                //for(Entry<K,V> entry: bucket)
                //{
                    //if(entry.getValue().equals(value))
                    //{
                        //return true;
                    //}
                //}
            //}
        //}
        //return false;
    //}

    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet();
    //{
        //java.util.Set<MyMap.Entry<K, V>> set = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        //for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        //{
            //if(table[i] != null)
            //{
                //LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[i];
                //for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
                //{
                    //set.add(entry);
                //}
            //}
        //}
        //return set;
    //}

    public V get(K key);
    //{
        //int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
        //if(table[bucketIndex] != null)
        //{
            //LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            //for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            //{
                //if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                //{
                    //return entry.getValue();
                //}
            //}
        //}
        //return null;
    //}

    //private int hash(int hashCode);
    //{
        //return supplementalHash(hashCode) & (capacity - 1);
    //}

    //private static int supplementalHash(int h);
    //{
        //h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        //return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
    //}

    public boolean isEmpty();
    //{
        //return size == 0;
    //}

    public Set<K> keySet();
    //{
        //java.util.Set<K> set = new java.util.HashSet<K>();
        //for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        //{
            //if(table[i] != null)
            //{
                //LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[i];
                //for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
                //{
                //  set.add(entry.getKey());
                //}
            //}
        //}
        //return set;
    //}

    public V put(K key, V value);
    //{
        //if(get(key) != null)
        //{
            //int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
            //LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            //for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            //{
                //if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                //{
                    //V oldValue = entry.getValue();

                    //entry.value = value;

                    //return oldValue;
                //}
            //}
        //}

        //if(size >= capacity * loadFactorThreshold)
        //{
            //if(capacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
            //{
                //throw new RuntimeException("Exceeding maximum capacity");
            //}

            //rehash();
        //}
        //int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());

        //if(table[bucketIndex] == null)
        //{
            //table[bucketIndex] = new LinkedList<Entry<K, V>>();
        //}

        //table[bucketIndex].add(new MyMap.Entry<K, V>(key, value));
        //size++;
        //return value;
    //}

    //private void rehash();
    //{
        //java.util.Set<Entry<K, V>> set = entrySet();
        //capacity <<= 1;
        //table = new LinkedList[capacity];
        //size = 0;
        //for(Entry <K, V> entry: set)
        //{
            //put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        //}
    //}

    public void remove(K key);
    //{
        //int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
        //if(table[bucketIndex] != null)
        //{
            //LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            //for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            //{
                //if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                //{
                    //bucket.remove(entry);
                    //size--;
                    //break;
                //}
        //  }
        //}
    //}

    public int size();
    //{
        //return size;
    //}

    public Set<V> values();
    //{
        //java.util.Set<V> set = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        //for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        //{
            //if(table[i] != null)
            //{
                //LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[i];
                //for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
                //{
                //  set.add(entry.getValue());
                //}
        //  }
        //}
        //return set;
    //}

    public String toString();
    //{
        //StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");
        //for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        //{
            //if(table[i] != null && table[i].size() > 0)
            //{
                //for(Entry<K, V> entry: table[i])
                //{
                    //builder.append(entry);
                //}
            //}
        //}
        //builder.append("]");
        //return builder.toString();
    //}

    public void insert(K k, V v);

    public E find(K k);
}
```

---

- When I tried to run it, it told me E cannot be resolved to a type for the public E
- find(K k) for both the MostHomophones and MyHashedMap. Not only is it a problem for both, but the find method appears to be incomplete in the MostHomophones.

Comment: Is there a way for me to fix the find method for both the codes MostHomophones and MyHashedMap?

Comment: What should these methods return? Were the signatures part of the assignment, or did you come up with them yourself? Are you allowed to change them?

Comment: the find methods should return the value of the first element in an array that pass a test. Furthermore , these two were originally based off of different classes. The MyHashedMap interface was originally a MyHashedMap class for a KeywordCounter and the MostHomophones was typed from scratch but  there were a few concepts based off of the other MostHomophones in github. The rest I added the methods from the MyHashedMap to be implemented.

Comment: Shouldn't it return a `V` then? Or possibly an `Optional<V>`? You didn't declare an `E` anywhere so far as far as I can see.

Comment: I changed it, but this is a problem now.

    public V find(K k)
As I used this for MostHomophones, it is telling me to return a type V and I got these errors.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\project2-input.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at MostHomophones.main(MostHomophones.java:271)

Answer (score 0):

I edited the programs. Also it turns out that the MyHashMap interface was a typo my professor made. It was actually a HashMap class and a MyMap interface to be used.

Here is the code so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MostHomophones
{
    MyHashMap<String , ArrayList<String>> lhm = new MyHashMap<>();
    String fileName;

    public MostHomophones()
    {

    }
    public MostHomophones(String inputFile)
    {
        this.fileName = inputFile;
    }
    private void scanFile()
    {
        File f = new File(this.fileName);
        try
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
            while(input.hasNext())
            {
                String s = input.nextLine();
                String[] line = s.split(" ");
                //todo
                lhm.put(s.substring(line[0].length()+1, s.length()), line[0]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void sortByValue()
    {
        TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        for(MyMap.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> ent: lhm.entrySet())
        {
            if(treeMap.containsKey(ent.value))
            {
                treeMap.get(ent.value).add(ent.key);
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<String> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
                toAdd.add(ent.key);
                treeMap.put(ent.value, toAdd);
            }
        }
        NavigableMap<String, ArrayList<String>> treeMap1 = treeMap.descendingMap();
        treeMap1.entrySet().forEach((ent) -> {
            System.out.println(ent.getKey() + ":" + ent.getValue());
        });
    }

    private void printCount()
    {
        for(MyMap.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> ent: lhm.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(ent.getKey()+":" + ent.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...strings)
    {
        MostHomophones kc = new MostHomophones("src/project2-input.txt");
        kc.scanFile();
        kc.sortByValue();       
        //kc.printCount();
    }
}


public interface MyMap<K, V>
{
    public void clear();

    public boolean containsKey(K key);

    public boolean containsValue(V value);

    public java.util.Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet();

    public V get(K key);

    public boolean isEmpty();

    public java.util.Set<K> keySet();

    public V put(K key, V value);

    public void remove(K key);

    public int size();

    public static class Entry<K, V>
    {
        K key;
        V value;

        public Entry(K key, V value)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public K getKey()
        {
            return key;
        }

        public V getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "[" + key + ", " + value + "]";
        }
    }
}



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyHashMap <K, V> implements MyMap<K, V>
{
    private static int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 4;
    private static int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;
    private int capacity;
    private static float DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;
    private float loadFactorThreshold;
    private int size = 0;

    ArrayList<MyMap.Entry<K,V>>[] table;

    public MyHashMap()
    {
        this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY, DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);
    }

    public MyHashMap(int initialCapacity)
    {
        this(initialCapacity, DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);
    }

    public MyHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactorThreshold)
    {
        if(initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        {
            this.capacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
        }
        else
        {
            this.capacity = trimToPowerOf2(initialCapacity);
        }

        this.loadFactorThreshold = loadFactorThreshold;
        table = new ArrayList[capacity];
    }

    private int trimToPowerOf2(int initialCapacity)
    {
        int capacity = 1;
        while(capacity < initialCapacity)
        {
            capacity <<= 1;
        }
        return capacity;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        size = 0;
        removeEntries();
    }

    private void removeEntries()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                table[i].clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key)
    {
        if(get(key) != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean containsValue(V value)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                ArrayList<Entry<K,V>> bucket = table[i];
                for(Entry<K,V> entry: bucket)
                {
                    if(entry.getValue().equals(value))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Set<MyMap.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()
    {
        java.util.Set<MyMap.Entry<K, V>> set = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                ArrayList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[i];
                for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
                {
                    set.add(entry);
                }
            }
        }
        return set;
    }

    public V get(K key)
    {
        int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
        if(table[bucketIndex] != null)
        {
            ArrayList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            {
                if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                {
                    return entry.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private int hash(int hashCode)
    {
        return supplementalHash(hashCode) & (capacity - 1);
    }

    private static int supplementalHash(int h)
    {
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public Set<K> keySet()
    {
        java.util.Set<K> set = new java.util.HashSet<K>();
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                ArrayList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[i];
                for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
                {
                    set.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
        return set;
    }

    public V put(K key, V value)
    {
        if(get(key) != null)
        {
            int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
            ArrayList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            {
                if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                {
                    V oldValue = entry.getValue();

                    entry.value = value;

                    return oldValue;
                }
            }
        }

        if(size >= capacity * loadFactorThreshold)
        {
            if(capacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exceeding maximum capacity");
            }

            rehash();
        }
        int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());

        if(table[bucketIndex] == null)
        {
            table[bucketIndex] = new ArrayList<Entry<K, V>>();
        }

        table[bucketIndex].add(new MyMap.Entry<K, V>(key, value));
        size++;
        return value;
    }

    private void rehash()
    {
        java.util.Set<Entry<K, V>> set = entrySet();
        capacity <<= 1;
        table = new ArrayList[capacity];
        size = 0;
        for(Entry <K, V> entry: set)
        {
            put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void remove(K key)
    {
        int bucketIndex = hash(key.hashCode());
        if(table[bucketIndex] != null)
        {
            ArrayList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[bucketIndex];
            for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
            {
                if(entry.getKey().equals(key))
                {
                    bucket.remove(entry);
                    size--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public Set<V> values()
    {
        java.util.Set<V> set = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
            {
                ArrayList<Entry<K, V>> bucket = table[i];
                for(Entry<K, V> entry: bucket)
                {
                    set.add(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        return set;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null && table[i].size() > 0)
            {
                for(Entry<K, V> entry: table[i])
                {
                    builder.append(entry);
                }
            }
        }
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

but when I tried to rerun it, it gave me these errors
for lhm.put(s.substring(line[0].length()+1, s.length()), line[0]); and treeMap.put(ent.value, toAdd);

The method put(String, ArrayList) in the type TreeMap> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList, ArrayList) for treeMap.put() and The method put(String, ArrayList) in the type MyHashMap> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String) for lhm.put()